Assigning consistent orientation to the simplicial faces of a polytope
Consider a list of $p$ points in $n$-dimensional space. A subset of $\{1,\dots p\}$, of length $n$ can be interpreted as indices of those points, forming an $(n-1)$-simplex.
Let there be given a list of such subsets, where each element represents a face of a given polytope. Eg: for $n=3$ this list:
l1 = {{1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {1, 4,5}, {4, 5, 6}, {2,3, 6}, {2, 5, 6}};

represents an octahedron.
I need to modify the elements of the above list so that all the faces ($n-1$ simplices) have the same orientation. Two faces are adjacent if their intersection has $n-1$ elements. Two adjacent faces have the same orientation if they match:
sameOrientation[face_, adjacent_] := 
  Signature[
     adjacent /. {Complement[adjacent, face][[1]] -> 
        Complement[face, adjacent][[1]]}] * Signature[face] == -1;

For example, in the unmodified list l1, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 5} have opposing orientations:

One solution for assigning consistent orientation to l1 would be:
l1Mod = {{1, 4, 3}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 5, 1}, {4, 6, 3}, {5, 4, 1}, {5, 6, 4}, {6,2, 3}, {6, 5, 2}}


What I'm looking for is a fast version of the algorithm that goes from l1 to l1Mod. I know it's essentially a graph traversal algorithm where the faces ($n-1$ simplices) are the elements of the graph, but I have no experience with working with graphs in Mathematica (or whether a graph would truly be the best to use in this situation), so the implementation would probably be slower than it needs to be.

Are you happy with the $n=3$ case only? Do you want a code which works for general dimensions? In the latter case, please provide some sample data.

Graphs are useful for organizing thoughts, but they are not always necessary. The following code constructs a graph gluingGraph which shows the (in)consistent gluing among simplices, but the graph itself is never used. Essential part is done by SatisfiabilityInstance[].
Clear["Global`*"];

orientPolytope[data_List] := 
  Module[{n, vertices, edges, del, sameOrientationQ, conflicting, 
    consistent, cond, sol, turnOver, x, gluingGraph},
   {n} = Union[Length /@ data]; 
   (* n = Length of point-tuples; 
   　　the basic simplices are (n-1) dimensional.*)
   vertices = data;  
   (* list of simplices *)
   edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ 
     Select[Subsets[vertices, {2}], 
      Length[Intersection @@ #] == n - 1 &];
   (* pairs of simplices which shares a facet. *)
   sameOrientationQ[t1_ \[UndirectedEdge] t2_] := (Signature[t1]*
       Signature[t2/. {Complement[t2,t1][[1]] -> 
           Complement[t1,t2][[1]]}] == -1);
   consistent = Select[edges, sameOrientationQ]; 
   conflicting = Complement[edges, consistent]; 
   gluingGraph = Graph[vertices, edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]; 
   gluingGraph = HighlightGraph[gluingGraph, 
         Style[#, Blue, Thick] & /@ conflicting];
   Print[gluingGraph];
   (* Graph of gluing: 
   If the edge t1 <-> t2 is blue, 
   then the simplicies t1 and t2 have opposite orientations. *)
   cond = And @@ Join[
      Xor[x[#[[1]]], x[#[[2]]]] & /@ conflicting,
      Not[Xor[x[#[[1]]], x[#[[2]]]]] & /@ consistent
      ];
   (* x[simplex] is a Boolean variable which means: 
      False -> "leave it as is", 
      True -> "must be turned over". *)
   sol = SatisfiabilityInstances[cond, x /@ vertices];
   If[Length[sol] == 0, 
      Print["There is no consistent orientation."]; Return[]];
   turnOver[True,simplex_]:=Join[simplex[[{2,1}]],simplex[[3;;]]];
   turnOver[False,simplex_]:=simplex;
   MapThread[turnOver, {sol[[1]], data}]
   ];

Test:
l1={{1,3,4},{1,2,3},{1,2,5},{3,4,6},{1,4,5},{4,5,6},{2,3,6},{2,5,6}};
l1mod = orientPolytope[l1]


(*{{1,3,4},{1,2,3},{2,1,5},{4,3,6},{1,4,5},{5,4,6},{3,2,6},{2,5,6}}*)

Non-orientable example: The right and left edges are glued together.

moebiusband={{1,2,5},{1,3,4},{1,3,6},{1,4,5},{2,3,6},{2,5,6}};
orientPolytope[moebiusband]


(* There is no consistent orientation. *)

Example of $n=4$:
l2 = RandomSample[Append[#, 0]] & /@ PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "FaceIndices"]

(* {{8,2,12,0},{2,8,0,7},{2,11,0,7},{2,11,0,4},{2,12,4,0},
   {9,1,0,5},{1,5,6,0},{6,0,10,1},{10,0,1,3},{9,0,3,1},
   {0,8,10,12},{3,8,0,7},{9,0,11,7},{5,11,4,0},{0,4,12,6},
   {5,9,11,0},{4,5,0,6},{6,10,0,12},{0,8,10,3},{9,0,3,7}} *)

l2mod = orientPolytope[l2]


(* {{8,2,12,0},{8,2,0,7},{2,11,0,7},{11,2,0,4},{12,2,4,0},
   {1,9,0,5},{5,1,6,0},{0,6,10,1},{10,0,1,3},{9,0,3,1},
   {0,8,10,12},{3,8,0,7},{9,0,11,7},{11,5,4,0},{0,4,12,6},
   {9,5,11,0},{5,4,0,6},{10,6,0,12},{8,0,10,3},{0,9,3,7}} *)

